# How to make MLflow server secure, scalable and increase the overall speed?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, nginx, mlflow

We have set up an MLflow server for the data science team of our company. it resides as a docker image . as of now nothing extra has been added . its just pure mlflow docker image.

following are the configurations of the mlflow server :

Backend Store :  Azure sql database.

Artifact store:  Azure Blob storage

There are 2 major problems which i can see

1. No authentication or Security layer on top of Mlflow eventhough necessary firewall rules have been set in the SQL instance.
2. experiment logging even for simple experiments is slow and when multiple people in the team log experiments simultaneously or trying to retrieve data from the server. it becomes even more slower.

What am i trying to achieve?

1. making the server scalable so that tomorrow even if 50 people log into the server there should be a mechanism to manage the load.
2. Even though we have a docker image ready. if something happens to the VM we will need to pull the docker image again and configure. Can kubernetes solve any of these issues and how?
3. A User authentication mechanism for MLflow.
4. A mechanism for load balancing in case many requests come up into the server as mentioned
   in the first point.

I have explored various options like

1. getting kubernetes into the picture.
2. using nginx.
3. using mysql Docker image and storing database there.

Need a clear idea how i can improve the whole flow.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify in your question,  A) Backend Store: is it MS SQL or MySQL? and B) Artifact Store:  Azure MS SQL or MySQL BLOB Storage?   You can edit your content, please.

Comment: What does this mean: "Even though we have a docker image ready. if something happens to the VM we will need to pull the docker image again and configure"

Comment: ok. we have a Azure VM inside which our mlflow docker image is running. what i mean is that if we decide to create a new vm we have to pull the docker image from docker hub again . is there a way around this?

Comment: Backend Store : Azure MYSql
Artifact Store : MySQL BLOB storage 

please let me know if anything is better than the other